# Why there is no "start_monitor" for gen_server?

Tags: erlang, monitor, erlang-otp, gen-server

Is there any particular reason why there is no `start_monitor` as an equivalent of `spawn_monitor`?

Is this simply not needed since gen_servers are usually started by supervisors?

I would like to get a notifications when my temporary workers crash. What is the recommended way to do this in an OTP application?
First idea was to have a `gen_server` which would monitor workers started by a dynamic supervisor.

**More Info:**

As far as I know supervisors provide controlled start, shutdown and controlled restart in case of a crash (to get back to a well defined state).
In addition to that, I would like to run a function when a worker process crashes.

For example, I have a C nodes which connect to the Erlang node. Since the C node can't monitor processes (AFAIK) and is also limited in other ways how it can interact with Erlang, I have a "proxy" processes for connecting C nodes in order to keep the C node as simple as possible.

The C nodes do rpc calls to Erlang using `ei_rpc_to` and processing messages from the connected Erlang node. Messages are either results of rpc calls or "out-of-band" data/info for the C node.

The Erlang "proxy" process monitors its C node using `monitor_node` to detect if it vanished, but I also need a mechanism for informing the C node that its proxy process crashed. One way of detecting this would be when it does the next rpc call, since it would obviously fail, but since I already have the "out-of-band" message processing in place, I wanted to use that.

Other use case would be having clients which do REST requests to the Erlang cluster. This in turn starts workers that perform some tasks (which may take a long time). After a while the external client may want to get the status of the task. The worker can for example update the status in a Mnesia table, but if it crashes, who will update the table with the failure status.

I know there are many ways of achieving this, but I would like to know what is the Erlang way of doing this.

**2nd Edit:**

After reading the docs I saw that in a `gen_server`, `terminate` will get called (if it is defined with a matching clause). Would this be a viable option to a separate monitoring process? This looks a bit messy since `terminate` does not get called when receiving 'EXIT' from other processes, so I would also need to trap exits

Comment: Why would you need both a monitor and a supervisor for these child processes? Why is a supervisor not sufficient? Maybe you can explain more about what you're trying to do and what you hope to get from a monitor that a supervisor can't provide.

Comment: @SteveVinoski for details on what I want to achieve, please see the updated question